# Start background thread on form load

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

Need to ask you for help as I'm struggling with this for too long now. 
Have gone over many tutorials but ended up with... nothing.

So, I have a ServiceProcess class with GetServicesToList(). This method populates Service object with list of services.

What I'm doing now, I'm reading a cache exactly a file (with services) at the app run time and this displays the data in a datagridView. GetServicesToList() is also invoked when form button is pressed.

This task takes up to 10 mins due to servers availability issues.

What I want to achieve, with help of BackgroundWorker class is to start this method at the run time, doing it over and over again with each time after it will complete to update my DataGridView as well as update cache (outputFile).
And all this without user being interrupt by this process.

I was trying to invoke this method already in BackgroundWord_DoWork() but due to my ServiceProcess Class using ServiceBase (class ServicesProcess : ServiceBase) I can't declare this method against BackgroundWorker.

Hope I have expressed myself with enough details so you guys could get the idea of what I'm trying to achieve. If anything is unclear ask for details.

Can someone help me out with this one?

```
public class ServicesProcess : ServiceBase, IEquatable<ServiceBase>
{
    private static string _machine = Services.GetServiceConfig();//ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("machineName");
    private static List<Service> _servicesList;
    private static ServiceController[] _services;
    private List<ServiceController> _holder;
    private List<string> _configList;
    private static ObjectToSerialize _objectToSerialize;

    public List<Service> GetServicesToList()
    {
        //_services = ServiceController.GetServices(_machine);
        var result = MemoryCache.Default.Get(Name) as List<Service>;
        if (result != null)
            return result;

        try
        {

            _configList = new List<string>(Services.GetAllServicesConfig());
            _holder = new List<ServiceController>();
            foreach (string t in _configList)
            {
                _services = ServiceController.GetServices(t);
                _holder.AddRange(_services);
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {

        }
        const string sPattern = "CSP";
        int i = 0;

        var cspServices = _holder.Where(x => x.DisplayName.Trim().StartsWith(sPattern)).ToList();

        _servicesList = new List<Service>();

        for (i = 0; i < cspServices.Count; i++)
        {
            Service obj = new Service
            {
                ServiceName = cspServices.ElementAt(i).DisplayName,
                ServiceVersion =
                    GetFileVersion(
                        GetFilePath(cspServices.ElementAt(i).ServiceName, cspServices.ElementAt(i).MachineName),
                        @"\\" + cspServices.ElementAt(i).MachineName + "\\"),
                ServiceStatus = cspServices.ElementAt(i).Status.ToString()
            };

            _servicesList.Add(obj);

        }

        _objectToSerialize = new ObjectToSerialize { Services = _servicesList };

        Serializer serializer = new Serializer();


        serializer.SerializeObject("outputFile.txt", _objectToSerialize);

        MemoryCache.Default.Set(Name, _servicesList, DateTimeOffset.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 0)));

        return _servicesList;
    }
```

That's the mothod that get all the services. Now in the design class, I want to use this method, as thread or task or background worked so this method will execute as background process. Have no idea how to do this...

And to help you visualize the app itself...
[image]

Comment: Create a Thread or a Task.

Comment: I'm new to .NET. I did look at the thread with async and await methods but did not got far.

Comment: ServiceBase is for services, not for desktop applications. i think you're on the wrong track with that. I also suggest a simple Task.Run() for now.

Comment: I'm using ServiceBase class to look up ServiceName. Ok... now i'm starting to worry.

Comment: Update include more explanations and some code.

Comment: is `GetServicesToList()` supposed to run on a bg thread?

Comment: @Chase Florell - Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of your goal, but if `GetServicesToList()` is supposed to be running in a background thread, can't you just implement `async` / `await`?

```
public async Task<List<Service>> GetServicesToList()
{
    return await Task.Run(() => {
        // all your old code
    });
}
```

and when you call it

```
var serviceList = await GetServicesToList();
```

I assume you're doing some sort of data binding, so when `serviceList` is hydrated, just pass it to the view.

---

Here's a self contained concept.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            SimulateTenButtonClicks();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static async void SimulateTenButtonClicks()
        {
            var foo = new Foo();
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var result = foo.DoStuff(i);
                Console.WriteLine(await result);
            }
        }

        public class Foo
        {
            public async Task<string> DoStuff(int i)
            {
                await Task.Delay(500); // simulate load
                return await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    return String.Format("I have been hit {0} times", i);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the continuation? Setting the field in the UI thread isn't an issue - in fact it's safer to set and check the flag from a single thread. The code will also be cleaner.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's not necessary, but I'm just wiring up a way to prevent multiple executions unnecessarily. If it's a 10 minute job and is kicked off by the press of a button, you don't want a user pressing the button 5x in a row. I would typically wire all of this up in an ICommand.

Comment: It says can't convert type bool to type of List<service>

Comment: @Jakubee, I simplified it, I had the continuation wrong anyways.

Comment: Ok. this puts me on a right track. And what about if I want to do it constantly. I mean, make this task update the file over and over again.